# How do you change the value of a text element already defined in a .fxml file in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Currently, I'm making a client-side anime streamer, and currently learning JavaFX.  I've created a static thumbnail, and I need to change the value of the static content.  So, how do you change the value of a text element already defined in a .fxml file in JavaFX?

For reference, here's the code.

`videoThumbnail.fxml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="387.0" prefWidth="243.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.gui.Controller">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="266.0" fitWidth="184.0" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="26.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../images/mL0215_1024x1024.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="36.0" layoutY="308.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" text="My Hero Acadamia" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

`main.java`

```java
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/videoThumbnail.fxml"));
            Pane root = (Pane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(root));

            primaryStage.setTitle("test");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            letterbox(scene, root);
            primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

`Controller.java`

```java
package test.gui;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class Controller {
}
```

Comment: In the controller : `@FXML Label yourLabel` and in the fxml file : `fx:id="yourLabel"` then you can use the object to change the values

Comment: @BoHalim how would you do that?

Comment: First your `Controller` class needs `implements Initializable`

Comment: @BoHalim The controller does not *need* to implement `Initializable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to assign an `id` attribute to the relevant tag. For example, if you wanted to reference the `AnchorPane` in the above FXML file, you would use this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="387.0" prefWidth="243.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.gui.Controller">
   ...
</AnchorPane>
```

Note the addition of `fx:id="anchorPane"`. That is the `id` attribute.

Now, you can reference it from the Controller by using the `id` as the variable name. Just add the `AnchorPane` as an instance variable using the `@FXML` annotation.

```java
package test.gui;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    /*Rest of class*/

}
```

You can do this with any object in the FXML file, including the `Label`s. Just remember to add the `id` attribute.

Comment: "_You can do this with any `Node` in the FXML file..._" – Not just any `Node`, but any `Object`.

Comment: @Slaw Good catch.